# Method Error with Quaternion class in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm still fairly new to the coding game and had some troubles getting the XNA framework into my C# program to use its quaternion math. Instead, perhaps a mistake, I found a zip file of the XNA geometry namespace and added it to a math library in my solution. Everything seemed to work perfectly aside from a single error at the very top of the most important class, the quaternion class.

```
namespace XnaGeometry
{
#if WINRT
    [DataContract]
#else
    [Serializable]
#endif
    public struct Quaternion : IEquatable<Quaternion>
    {
#if WINRT
        [DataMember]
#endif
        public double X;
#if WINRT
        [DataMember]
#endif
        public double Y;
#if WINRT
        [DataMember]
#endif
        public double Z;
#if WINRT
        [DataMember]
#endif
        public double W;

        static Quaternion identity = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1);


        public Quaternion(double x, double y, double z, double w)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Z = z;
            this.W = w;
        }
```

The error falls on the very first word "Quaternion" and says "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class." My attempts at guess and check repair from google searches and blind luck has proven fruitless. Anyone have a clue as to why this error popped up?

Comment: I think you're using an XNA Reserved word... See this [MSDN - Quaternion Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.quaternion.aspx).

Comment: I thought about that, but when I tried changing it to something different the error didn't change, aside from the 1 million other errors that appeared since I changed the name.